# How to use 'continue' in a PowerShell switch statement?

Tags: powershell, foreach, continue

I have a foreach loop as the following example:

```
foreach ($a in @(1,2,3,4))
{ switch ($a)
  { 1 { $x = "value a"
        Write-Host "Not yet supported."
        continue
        break
      }
    2 { $x = "value b"
        Write-Host "Not yet supported."
        continue
        break
      }
    3 { $x = "value c"
        break
      }
    4 { $x = "value d"
        break
      }
  }
  Write-Host $a
}
```

Expected output:

```
Not yet supported.
Not yet supported.
3
4
```

Actual output:

```
Not yet supported.
1
Not yet supported.
2
3
4
```

So the question is, why does a continue not work in a switch statement? I could rewrite it to a if statement, but that is no on my wish list...

P.S. The first two `breaks` shouldn't have any effect if `continue` works as expected. That is intended, because the not supported message will be deleted in the next weeks :)

**Edit:**

According to this post: [is there any difference in using a break or a continue statement within a switch statement?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3b6034f2-a880-455c-a7d6-a1caf4b9d9c2/is-there-any-difference-in-using-a-break-or-a-continue-statement-within-a-switch-statement?forum=winserverpowershell), switch can handle non scalar values...

Comment: I've just tried this and I get "Not yet supported" 1 "Not yet supported" 2 3 4 (on new lines obviously). It certainly looks like the "continue" isn't breaking out of the loop.

Comment: @ansgarwiechers How are nested loops related to a switch in a loop? These are different control structures. If you feel it's a duplicate, please add at least a comment how you came to this conclusion!

Comment: @Paebbels `switch` is a loop, so you have nested loops: `switch` loop inside `foreach` loop.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have seen many switch statements in many languages, but non has every claimed to be a loop ... Do you have a (documentation) link to proof your statement?

Comment: `continue` and `break` do the same thing here: leave the `switch` statement and continue with the next instruction (`Write-Host $a`). You need to continue at a label to avoid this. Which is what the accepted answer to the other question describes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers OK, thanks. I found an alternative: Instead of `continue`, a switch branch returns `$true`. The switch statement's return value is then assigned to a variable and this is tested for a break condition. But it's not so nice as using labels.

Comment: @Paebbels [`Get-Help` about_Break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break): *When a Break statement appears in a loop, such as a Foreach, For, **Switch**, or While loop,*

Comment: well, is this bugged? It still does not work. If I have a while loop and switch within and I want some cases to make it go back to the loop start it DOES NOT happen and continue behaves the same as break. I guess this is not going to be fixed after so many years...?